# how to check if input field has filled out and radio button has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if my input field has been filled out and one of my radio buttons has been selected. I tried the following:

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var empty = false;
    if ($('input[type="text"]').val() == '' && $(!$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val())) {
        empty = true;
    }
    if (empty) {
        $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work e.g. it only checks the `input`-field. can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to use `.prop()` to set the disabled state

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/L9hkp37w/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyup event won't be triggered on the radio select

```js
$('input').on('keyup change', function() {
  $('button').prop('disabled', $('input[type="text"]').val() == '' || !$('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button disabled>Save</button>
<input type="text" />
<input type="radio" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
      var empty = false;
      if ($('input[type="text"]').val() == '' && $('#radio_button').is(':checked')) {
             empty = true;
       }

       if (empty) {
            $('button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('button').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
 });
```